# Convert Lambda from C# to VB.NET

Tags: c#, vb.net, lambda

How would I translate this C# lambda expression into VB.NET ?

```
query.ExecuteAsync(op => op.Results.ForEach(Employees.Add));
```

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Ink;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using IdeaBlade.Core;
using IdeaBlade.EntityModel;
```

namespace SimpleSteps
{
    public class MainPageViewModel
    {
        public MainPageViewModel()
        {
            Employees = new ObservableCollection();
            var mgr = new NorthwindIBEntities();
            var query = mgr.Employees;
            query.ExecuteAsync(op => op.Results.ForEach(Employees.Add));
        }

```
    public ObservableCollection<Employee> Employees { get; private set; }
}
```

}

`` // Summary:
    //     Execute the query asynchronously.  IdeaBlade.EntityModel.EntityManager.ExecuteQueryAsync()
    //
    // Parameters:
    //   query:
    //     This query
    //
    // Type parameters:
    //   T:
    //     Entity type returned
    public static EntityQueryOperation<T> ExecuteAsync<T>(this IEntityQuery<T> query);
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Execute the query asynchronously.  IdeaBlade.EntityModel.EntityManager.ExecuteQueryAsync()
    //
    // Parameters:
    //   query:
    //     This query
    public static EntityQueryOperation ExecuteAsync(this IEntityQuery query);
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Execute the query asynchronously.  IdeaBlade.EntityModel.EntityManager.ExecuteQueryAsync()
    //
    // Parameters:
    //   query:
    //     This query
    //
    //   userCallback:
    //     Callback invoked when the query completes
    //
    //   userState:
    //     Token to identify the query upon completion
    //
    // Type parameters:
    //   T:
    //     Entity type returned
    //
    // Remarks:
    //     Provide a userCallback if you want to be notified when the operation completes.
    //      The query results will be returned in the IdeaBlade.EntityModel.EntityQueriedEventArgs
    //     passed to the userCallback.  Use the userState to uniquely identify this
    //     call.
    public static EntityQueryOperation<T> ExecuteAsync<T>(this IEntityQuery<T> query, Action<EntityQueryOperation<T>> userCallback, object userState = null);
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Execute the query asynchronously.  IdeaBlade.EntityModel.EntityManager.ExecuteQueryAsync()
    //
    // Parameters:
    //   query:
    //     This query
    //
    //   userCallback:
    //     Callback invoked when the query completes
    //
    //   userState:
    //     Token to identify the query upon completion
    //
    // Remarks:
    //     Provide a userCallback if you want to be notified when the operation completes.
    //      The query results will be returned in the IdeaBlade.EntityModel.EntityQueriedEventArgs
    //     passed to the userCallback.  Use the userState to uniquely identify this
    //     call.` ``

Comment: already try it,gives error
Error 1 Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'ExecuteAsync' can be called with these arguments

Comment: Again, *what is the definition of `ExecuteAsync`*? The IdeaBlade site doesn't provide any documentation. We need to know the actual signature of the method (what parameters it expects, all of the overloads, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

Starting with 2010, VB10 supports non-functional lambdas.

```
query.ExecuteAsync(Sub(op) op.Results.ForEach(Employees.Add))
```

Comment: also the same error
already try it,gives error
Error 1 Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'ExecuteAsync' can be called with these arguments

Comment: Can you provide the method definition for `ExecuteAsync`?

Comment: ....
using IdeaBlade.Core;
using IdeaBlade.EntityModel;

namespace SimpleSteps
{
    public class MainPageViewModel
    {
        public MainPageViewModel()
        {
            Employees = new ObservableCollection<Employee>();
            var mgr = new NorthwindIBEntities();
            var query = mgr.Employees;
            query.ExecuteAsync(op => op.Results.ForEach(Employees.Add));
        }

        public ObservableCollection<Employee> Employees { get; private set; }
    }
}

Comment: Err, please post it as an edit to your question, not as a comment.

Answer (score 1):

```
query.ExecuteAsync(Function(op) op.Results.ForEach(Employees.Add))
```

also you can do this here:
http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/

Answer (score -1):

I found the solution..

```
query.ExecuteAsync.Results.ForEach(Sub(o) Employees.Add(o))
```

Hope this helps to others